# SimpleSAMLphp response not handled

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

Have set up a SimpleSAMLphp configuration with correct metadata and login details. We can successfully login to the idp , and we can see responses back from the provider that show the detailed SAML response for the user. We are using the Chrome SAML-Tracer plugin, and we see all the assertions and account information for the user in the response, but the simple PHP test page below is stuck in a loop.

```
<?php
require_once ('../../simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');

$saml_auth = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');
if ($saml_auth->isAuthenticated()) {
    $attributes = $saml_auth->getAttributes();   
    var_dump($attributes);    
} else {
    $saml_auth->requireAuth();
}
```

Loops forever as the isAuthenticated is always false .... keeps trying to log in again , but provider returns SAML response over and over. Any suggestions as to what is going wrong ?   Ubuntu 20.04 , SimpleSAMLPHP v1.19

changed the metadata and config files, no luck

Comment: Further to my post above , since the SAML IDP is POSTing back SAML to my specified URL I am now intercepting the XML SAML data myself from the POST payload , then DOMDocumenting the XML and extracting the Assertions. It does not feel the right way to do this as the SimpleSAMLPHP isAuthenticated should be working, but having tried about 200 different changes to config, authsources and metadata , I simply cannot get it to work !!!!